# Storage used by contract reference

Tags: solidity

I'm not sure how many bytes are used by contract references in solidity. Are they addresses?

Would it make any sense to change

```
struct data {
        uint8 score;
        IERC20 token;
        uint8 index;
        uint256 price;
}
```

to

```
struct data {
        uint8 score;
        uint8 index;
        IERC20 token;
        uint256 price;
}
```

in order to reduce storage usage?

Answer (score 0):

They use 20 bytes since they only store the address. Because of that, the order between your two examples do not matter; both will be packed into the same 2 storage slots.

In your first example: 8 bits + 160 bits + 8 bits = 176 bits (< 256 bits)
In your second example: 8 bits + 8 bits + 160 bits = 176 bits (< 256 bits)

And in both examples your last struct field will be in a new storage slot since it fills an entire slot by itself

Answer (score 0):

Not in this case. Addresses are 20 bytes long, (and as you guessed, contract references in solidity are simply stored as addresses) so both your structs would take 2 slots (1+20+1 bytes in the first slot for both `uint8s` and the `address`, and 32 bytes in the second for the `uint256`). Now, in my opinion the second looks cleaner, so you might wanna go with that for the sake of code readability, but it won't change anything regarding storage.